# products unit in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have some problems with product unit in javascript.What im trying to do is  that 1st column to show only the unit of product.This are 2 columns of code that i have so far.The 1st one is for product unit that show wrong value and second is for product quantity and work perfectly.what i did wrong in 1st column?

For Product unit=`tr_html += 'input name="munit[]" type="hidden" "' + product_unit + '">"' + product_unit + '"';`

For Product quantity=`tr_html += 'input name="quantity_balance[]" type="hidden" class="rbqty" value="' + item_bqty + '"input class="form-control text-center rquantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" tabindex="'+((site.settings.set_focus == 1) ? an : (an+1))+'" value="' + formatQuantity2(item_qty) + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="quantity_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"input name="product_unit[]" type="hidden" class="runit" value="' + product_unit + '"input name="product_base_quantity[]" type="hidden" class="rbase_quantity" value="' + base_quantity + '"';`

Comment: Maybe if you formatted the code nicely it would be easier to tell. Please edit your question and use the code button.

Comment: I tried to edit it, but couldn't make heads or tails what the original intended code should be ;)